# Removing X-axis tiling of google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In a given instance of google maps...

Is there a way to turn off the other instances of the maps which tile to the right and left of the initial central map?

I've seen ways to restrict the pan ability of the map ... but it uses lat + lng to determine when to re-center the map ... and thus the usage falls apart at different zoom levels.

For example: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

If on zooms all the way out, you can see how the map of the globe is tiled along the x-axis.

I would like a single instance of the map.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an observer to the **zoom_changed** event, and set the **minZoom** if more than 90 degrees of map is shown. The second statement recursively reduces the zoom to an acceptable limit before the limit is known.

```
var zoomObserver = function () {
    width = Math.abs(map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat() - 
        map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat());
    if (width > 90){
            var opt = { minZoom: map.getZoom()};
            map.setOptions(opt);
    }
    if (width > 179){
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
    }
};
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed', zoomObserver );
```

This simple solution works for most use cases, doesn't take into account doubling the width of the map through resizing the browser window, so you may need to add the observer to another event in that case.